# Checking file size gt 0 in Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, size

I did search for help regarding my subject but did not find something close to what I need, then here is my doubt:

I need to check the size of a file in a specific folder, if it´s greater than 0 bytes, it´s OK to continue the process, else, abort it writing an output message and sending fail code = 1.

I´ve tried the below but no success on writing the message to the log:

```
$FileExists1 = "D:\TEST\FILE\test.txt"

IF (Test-Path $FileExists1) {
    If ((Get-Item $FileExists1).length -gt 0kb) {
      Write-Output [$(Get-Date)]:" FILE IS OK FOR PROCESSING! - RC = $rc"
    }

Else {
      $rc = 1
      Write-Output [$(Get-Date)]:" FILE HAS 0 BYTES AT D:\TEST\FILE\"
      Write-Output [$(Get-Date)]:" VALIDATION FINISHED - RC = $rc"
      Exit $rc
    }
}
```

Does any of you know what I could do?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You'll get better answers to your question if you tag it with the programming language you're asking about, rather than just "file" and "size"

Comment: Thanks Ari, just updated it.

Comment: What does "*but no success on writing the message to the log:*" mean? What log?

Comment: when I say log I mean the output from Write-Output, I´m running this script from Autosys where I have set an output folder to save my log, then it triggers my script and writes msgs there.

Comment: What you posted works fine, but you have not shared how you are logging... My guess is your problem isn't in the code you've provided.

Comment: While you "log output" works I would suggest you quote it better: `Write-Output "[$(Get-Date)]:' FILE HAS 0 BYTES AT D:\TEST\FILE\'"`. Is your issue just logging? Does this code work outside Autosys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code works absolutely fine. However make sure you provide an initial value to your "$rc".

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> 

$FileExists1 = 'E:\Work\Powershell\scripts\demo\demo.txt'

IF (Test-Path $FileExists1) {
    If ((Get-Item $FileExists1).length -gt 0kb) {
      Write-Output [$(Get-Date)]:" FILE IS OK FOR PROCESSING! - RC = $rc"
    }

Else {
      $rc = 1
      Write-Output [$(Get-Date)]:" FILE HAS 0 BYTES AT D:\TEST\FILE\"
      Write-Output [$(Get-Date)]:" VALIDATION FINISHED - RC = $rc"
      Exit $rc
    }
}
[09/02/2016 23:55:15]: FILE HAS 0 BYTES AT D:\TEST\FILE\
[09/02/2016 23:55:15]: VALIDATION FINISHED - RC = 1
```

However, if you run the code again in the same scope, the value of the variable $rc will be 1. So make sure, you re-initialize the value to 0 or something else, so it might not produce a wrong result.

Comment: yeah, I have it initialized as $rc=0, was a copy and paste issue here. The problem then seems to be using this with Autosys. :(

Comment: Then your question should reference Autosys and how you are using it...?

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue with outputting the log? Write-output is going to write to the console host. Use out-file or tee-object instead

"[$(Get-Date)]:' FILE HAS 0 BYTES AT D:\TEST\FILE\'" | Out-file D:\example.log

Also your variable $rc is undefined if the file is bigger than 0.